# SQL Server : how to merge XML into several tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, merge

My schema has 3 levels and goes like this:

Triggers

```
TRIGGER_ID (PK), TARGET_GROUP_SERIAL, EVENT_ID, START_DATE, END_DATE, MEASURE_FIELD, IS_ACTIVE, PRIORITY
```

TriggerActions

```
TRIGGER_ID, TRIGGER_DETAIL_ID (PK + Identity Insert), ACTION_ID, ISOLATION_VOLUME
```

ActionChannels

```
TRIGGER_DETAIL_ID (PK), EXECUTION_METHOD_ID
```

Now, my input is an XML file which and I need to merge it into the DB schema, the XML can look like below,

Notice that if the XML does not contain a TriggerID in the RealTimeTrigger it means a new trigger and when the ActionDetailId = 0 it means a new action

Any suggestions?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ArrayOfRealTimeTrigger xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <RealTimeTrigger>
    <TargetGroupSerial>3</TargetGroupSerial>
    <ClientTriggerId>1</ClientTriggerId>
    <StartDate>2014-08-06T00:00:00</StartDate>
    <EndDate>2014-09-03T00:00:00</EndDate>
    <MeasureField>FIELD4</MeasureField>
    <IsActive>true</IsActive>
    <Priority>999</Priority>
    <ControlGroupPercentage>20</ControlGroupPercentage>
    <Actions>
      <RealTimeAction>
        <ActionDetailId>0</ActionDetailId>
        <Id>12</Id>
        <Channels>
            <Channel>
                <ChannelId>100</ChannelId>
                <ChannelId>201</ChannelId>
            </Channel>
        </Channels>
        <ActionPrecentage>40</ActionPrecentage>
      </RealTimeAction>
      <RealTimeAction>
        <ActionDetailId>0</ActionDetailId>
        <Id>13</Id>
        <Channels>
            <Channel>
                <ChannelId>100</ChannelId>
                <ChannelId>201</ChannelId>
            </Channel>
        </Channels>
        <ActionPrecentage>40</ActionPrecentage>
      </RealTimeAction>
    </Actions>
  </RealTimeTrigger>
</ArrayOfRealTimeTrigger>'
```

Comment: According to the tag wiki, "[tag:Scheme] is a functional programming language in the Lisp family, closely modelled on lambda calculus with eager (applicative-order) evaluation." This doesn't appear to have anything to do with [tag:scheme], so I've removed the tag.  Please be sure to read the tag descriptions when adding them to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there aren't id values I the XML linking the child elements together (if the are linked just by nesting in XML) then I would use a select with ROWNUMBER to assign temporary ids to the rows that were in the XML. Then I think you could do a [MERGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625(v=sql.100).aspx) into the triggers table with an  into a table variable. In that table variable you can have a column for the original/ROWNUMBER based id and a column for the id as it was inserted for the new records. Then you have enough data to join things together and repeat for the next two levels.

Let me know if you need more details, or maybe this is enough for someone else to expand upon.

Comment: @Yairt I see you marked this as the best answer. Was this enough to solve your problem? If so and you happen to be able to post the complete, working answer to your question I think it would be awesome if you could post it as an answer here.